# How to load, and delete dynamically Nodes in javafx?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I need to dynamically load list of button and add action listner to all of them basic on user decision. Next I have to delete this buttons and load instead of them other buttons. I tried to use this code,

```
public void clearRadioButtons()
{


    for(int i =0; i< radioButtons.size() -1;i++)
    {
        radioButtons.remove(i);
        group.getToggles().remove(i);
        vBox.getChildren().remove(radioButtons);

    }
    radioButtons.clear();
    group.getToggles().clear();
    System.out.println("Clear"+radioButtons.size());


}
```

but these radiobuttons still are on my screen. I can't delete them. Does somebody know how to dynamically load, delete and load something instead of them?

Answer (score 1):

`List`'s `remove(Object)` method only removes an element, if the object passed as parameter is part of the list. Passing a list doesn't result in a modification of the list.

Also the loop is implemented incorrectly (unless you don't want to remove the last `RadioButton` and skip every other radio button).

Use `removeAll(Collection)` instead to remove the radio buttons. Using `clear` may also be an option, unless there are other children of the `VBox`.

**Example:**

```
private final List<RadioButton> radioButtons = new ArrayList<>();
private final ToggleGroup toggleGroup = new ToggleGroup();
private VBox vBox;

private void clearRadios() {
    vBox.getChildren().removeAll(radioButtons); // remove from scene
    radioButtons.clear(); // remove from list
    toggleGroup.getToggles().clear(); // remove from ToggleGroup
}

private void addRadios(int count) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        RadioButton radio = new RadioButton();
        radio.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);
        radioButtons.add(radio);
        vBox.getChildren().add(radio);
    }
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Button btn = new Button("add");
    btn.setOnAction(evt -> addRadios(5));

    Button btn2 = new Button("clear");
    btn2.setOnAction(evt -> clearRadios());

    vBox = new VBox(btn, btn2);

    stage.setScene(new Scene(vBox, 300, 500));
    stage.show();
}
```